# Custom Joomla Template Nav Bar Formatting Issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I am designing a custom Joomla template for a website on which I am working, and the design is very unique.  Up until this point, the project has been going well, but now I am having a css issue with the navigation bar, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why I cannot fix it.  This is the page with the nav bar correctly positioned using HTML and CSS without the Bootstrap framework that integrates with Joomla.

[image: Template Layout with HTML/CSS and no bootstrap]

As I said, that is perfect.  As soon as I add the bootstrap css, however, I end up with the nav bar appearing like below and nothing I do will fix it.

[image: Template Layout with bootstrap]

Please refer to my index.html and custom.css files below.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrap-extended.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<header role="banner" class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8">
        <a href="/"><img src="images/site_logo.png" alt="Shamrock Tours, click for home." id="headerimage"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
    User menu goes here.
    </div>
</header>

<nav class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
    Nav menu goes here.
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="innerbody">
<aside class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
    Sidebar goes here.
    </div>
</aside>

</body>
</html>
```

custom.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Main Styles for Shamrock Tours Website */

/* CSS Reset */

a,
article,
aside,
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
html,
img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


/* General Element Styling */

html {
    background: #0D8330;
}

body {
    border: 5px double #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family: "IM Fell French Canon";
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 1em;

}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2.25em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.125em;
}


/* Header */

header {
    margin: 25px 25px 0;
}

#headerimage {
    float: left;
    width: 41%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    line-height: 2;
}

header h1 {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    left: 150px;
    width: 500px;
    text-shadow: 1px -1px #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Navigation */

nav {
    position: relative;
    top: -70px;
    left: 345px;
    height: 75px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px #666;
    background: rgba(8,138,43,0.9);
    line-height: 2;
}

/* Content */

#innerbody {
    position: relative;
    top: -103px;
    width: 95%;
    min-height: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 75px 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: -1;
}

article {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;

}

article h2 {
    margin: 1.05em 0;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #666;
}

article h3 {
    line-height: 1.2;
}

aside {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

/* Footer */

#footercontainer {
    position: relative;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 0.875em;
}
```

Any suggestions you can provide on the problem and a solution would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having a look at the live site, it's a bit tricky to pinpoint it for you. It looks like something within your HTML is being targeted by the bootstrap CSS with a stronger selector than yours thus it's killing your menu. You could expend on your CSS selectors to be more precise, or you could add '!important' to the end of each CSS rule to do with your menu (but most say this is bad practice). If you pull it up in chrome and do an inspect element, you can pinpoint an area and see every bit of CSS that's affecting it and where that's pulling from.

This is the exact reason I don't use Bootstrap, half your time is wasted fighting it!